# How do I open a Fragment on dialog click?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialog, fragmentmanager

I created a Dialog box like this:

My Dialog Fragment:

```
package com.aaron.waller.mrpolitik;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class extendsDialog extends Dialog implements
        android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public Activity c;
    public Dialog d;
    public ImageButton yes, no;

    public extendsDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        yes = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
        no = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
        yes.setOnClickListener(this);
        no.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_yes:
                break;
            case R.id.btn_no:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }



}
```

Now I want that if I click on "btn_yes" that a Fragment opens. I tried it like that:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_yes:
                    FragmentManager fm = c.getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.parteienlayout, new SPD());
                    ft.addToBackStack( "Tag");
                    ft.commit();
                    break;
        case R.id.btn_no:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
}
```

But then it says "wrong 2nd argument type "new SPD""

I also tried to put this in my MainActivity.java:

```
    public void tocdu(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.customdialog, new CDU());
        ft.addToBackStack( "Tag");
        ft.commit();
}
```

and this on dialog click:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_yes:
            ((MainActivity)getContext()).tocdu();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_no:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
}
```

but its still not working.
How can I achive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `SPD.class`

```
public class SPD extends Fragment {}
```

Make sure to import the following package:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

the idea is if you use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

then use: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in your called framgent

or if you use `getFragmentManager()`

you have to use: `import android.app.Fragment;`